# How to get a value equivalent to the RFC22 size of an entire email message by using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, size, imap, rfc822

I’d like to know how possible is to get a value equivalent to the RFC22 size of an email message by using Microsoft Graph API.

The RFC822 size is defined as “RFC822.SIZE is the number of octets in the message when the message is expressed in [RFC5322] format” (see [reference](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc9051.html#section-2.3.4)).
The most similar field returned by MS Graph API I was able to find is the `PidTagMessageSize` (see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessagesize-canonical-property)), which “Contains the sum, in bytes, of the sizes of all properties on a message object.“.

IMAP allows the possibility of obtaining the RFC822 size directly with the `FETCH` command. See:

```
. fetch 1:4 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID)] RFC822.SIZE)
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen) RFC822.SIZE 1910 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS ("MESSAGE-ID")] {60}
Message-ID: <8984267.1075855214866.JavaMail.evans@thyme>

)
. OK Success
```

To get the `PidTagMessageSize` with Graph API, the `singularValueExtendedProperty` `0x0E08` has to be included explicitly in the query (see
[GraphAPI explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygwsI.png)).

These are examples for the same email message (check the Message-ID is the same in both IMAP / Graph API cases). However, the size returned by IMAP (RFC822.SIZE **1910**) is different than the value returned by Graph API ({ “id”: “Long 0xe08”, “value”: “**6116**” }).

Is there a way to get the same value IMAP returns, i.e. RFC822 size, by using Graph API or at least a unique relation that can be applied in order to calculate that size form the value returned by GraphAPI, i.e. `PidTagMessageSize`?

Thank you.